# How to destroy magic without destroying whole world?

Tags: magic, technological-development

I plan to end fantasy stories line with destroying magic - and let that world to be without magic - to it would be converted into SF/utopistic (or so) world.

---

Currently I have following idea: Convert magic to else (classic) materials (and also natural rules, as described below).

This way has been already started - when conversion of magic into classic materials was discovered and industrial way of this conversion was prepared for usage. However, this process is not perfect and small amount of magic stays.

Conversion of magic into classic materials would be ended in great battle, when rest of magic would be definitely converted into various classic materials (rather: elements, like iron, copper, carbon and so on, including heavy ones like uranium or so) and natural rules (gravity or so).

Also, this change would bring new type of magic: magic that is (due to knowledge) not distinguishable from technology. This type of magic was first described by Icefingers and Warmsteel, but this *work* had to be held because most people did not accept it (and they did not believed in this work at first, too).

But of course, this change would, due to speed of final step, cause terrible chaos leading to very increased mortality and rise of religiosity and belief (and also wrath of gods on people).

---

**But what else way to use to destroy magic - without destroying whole world** (if it is magic world)**?**

Comment: Do you have an existing series of fantasy/magic stories?

Comment: Just add 7 magical volcanoes at the beginning of time, and they leak magic in form of the elements since then. Then magic ended(or cooled down enough) because it was finite and trough those volcanoes it was converted to industrial valuable materials. End of story, live the artifacts, then they cooled down again, welcome steam punk and second industrial revolution.

Comment: How to destroy magic? Let's see: Angry gods withhold the magic. The lodestone source is neutralized. The psychic link is broken. The demons consumed the portal energy. Humans used up all the magic. The warp field became destabilized. Sunspots. Kangaroos.

Comment: Larry Niven's series — the magic goes away, and civilization needs to start over using nonmagical methods.

Comment: You need to first define what magic is and where it comes from.

Comment: Magic could work as the positive and negative electric charges. With time, all of the positive and negative charges would find their pairs. From that point, there is no magic any more.